# Delegate events to canvas and retrieve the Element in the handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, raphael

I'm using **Raphaël** to draw a **graph (network)** as **nodes** are represented and shown as circles. The user can **dynamically add nodes** by clicking on the canvas, and by that the newly constructed `Element` object is pushed into a `Set`, also into a model object, where some precious data stored about the node just created.

I want to **show the mentioned data** from the model near each node, when the user brings the mouse pointer **over a node**. What I wish to avoid is to create a new event on every node at creation. I want to **delegate the event to the canvas** to have a global handler for each node.

I've already created such handler and attached the event to it:

```
var Paper    = Raphael('Graph',600,600),
    $Canvas  = $(Paper.canvas),
    onMouseOver = function(e){
      // Wish to have an Element object
    }

$Canvas.on('mouseover','circle',onMouseOver);
```

The event and the handler works fine, as it fires only on circles.

How can I retrieve or **take it as an `Element` object**, and access its `.data()` and every associated? Do I have to search for it in my `Set`? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the elements in your set are identified by Raphaël's `Element.id` then as you create new elements you can assign the equivalent id to the DOM node

```
newElement = Paper.circle(x, y, r);
newElement.node.id = newElement.id;
```

Then in your mouseover handler you can get the element's id from the `event.target`

```
onMouseOver = function(e){
  var elemId = e.target.id;
  //find your element in the set by this id to get the precious data
}
```

Comment: Sadly, there is no getter on a `Set`, which returns `Element`s by their ID. I might have to iterate over the `Set` with the function `forEach` implemented on the `Set`.

Comment: I haven't used Raphaël's Set object before, but iteration does seem to be the only way to find an element in it. However, if the data is stored on the element you could just get it with `Paper.getByID()` regardless of whether the element is in the Set right?